# SFML Error with C++, Entry Point Not Found

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

I get the error "The procedure point __gxx_personality_v0 could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll   How can I fix this? I have no idea and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What OS, what compiler etc, and your code might actually help!

Comment: How about googling for gxx_personality_v0?

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler is using a different version of libstdc++-6.dll then the binary of SFML that you downloaded. What this basically means is that when SFML compiled the version of the library you downloaded they used a different version of libstdc++ then you have on your computer which will obviously cause problems most of the time.

Here is probably the best solution to this problem.

You will need to compile from the source. You will need a few things to do this. First go out and get CMake which is available here. Then go and download the SFML 2.1 source code http://www.sfml-dev.org/download.php (Or whatever version you want). Next to figure out how to compile from the source code you can follow this tutorial http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/compile-with-cmake.php .

Once everything is compiled link to the new libraries that you created specifically for your compiler and you should be good to go.

Comment: When you say download SFML source code, do you mean to click the "Source Code" button on the bottom left of the download page?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your gcc version is (very) different from what SFML library is built with?
The best solution is to build the source yourself, with your compiler.

Comment: I have seen this same issue before, and can confirm that this solution is what solved it.