# SFML library entry point

Tags: debugging, sfml

When using the SFML library I am encountering this error message:

[image: error message]

What does it mean and how do I solve it?

code :

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

P.S. I followed this video to install SFML library: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fcZFaiGFIMA

Comment: Can you provide an approximate translation of the error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/21152699/654614?  Other (possibly) related questions include: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18647280/654614,    https://stackoverflow.com/q/7751640/654614 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/14889407/654614?

Comment: 1. Are you working on Linux, 2. Are you compiling with gcc, 3. Are you 100% certain you downloaded the proper files. __gxx_personality_sj0 clearly cannot be found in the sfml-graphics-2.dll. This is something that would only be needed for compiling with gcc, so I imagine you downloaded the wrong SFML files, or potentially have improperly linked them.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you haven't linked correctly the dll library or it is linked but not in the same folder as your project